# Filling 4l, 5l bottles from two 10l bottles

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle

There are two bottles of 10litre each filled with water.

Now two persons having empty bottles of 4litre and 5litre want to take 2litres of water each from the previous 10litre bottles..

Now you have to pour the water without wasting or throwing it.

This is an question in a previous placement paper. I was not getting how to proceed.
Can anyone give me some hint....

Comment: To begin with, you might consider how to get at least one 2L quantity. Fill the 5L bottle from one of the 10L bottles, then fill the 4L bottle from the 5L bottle, leaving 1L in the latter. Empty the 4L bottle back into the 10L bottle you poured from initially, and transfer the 1L of water from the 5L bottle to the 4L bottle. Fill the 5L bottle again, and fill the 4L bottle from it. There is only room for 3L, leaving 2L behind in the 5L bottle. Now play around along these lines and see what else is possible. (We haven't even touched the other 10L bottle so far.)

Comment: I think there is some ambiguity here as to what the desired outcome is. Does "take 2 litres of water each" imply that the water from the two big bottles shouldn't be mixed? Or is all of the water interchangeable, such that this should be understood only as saying that the big bottles should finish each containing 8 litres?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call containers by $A=10,B=10,C=5,D=4$.

Start by pouring $A$ into $C$, then $B$ into $D$.  Pour $D$ into $A$, then $C$ into $B$, then $C$ into $D$.  Now you have $1$ in $D$.  Pour from $A$ into $C$, then from $C$ into $D$, leaving $2$ in $C$.  Now pour from $D$ into $A$, then $B$ into $D$, then $D$ into $A$ again, leaving $2$ in $D$.

Alternate recipe (among many), uses "front loading":

Pour $A$ into $D$, $D$ into $C$, $A$ into $D$, $D$ into $C$, $C$ into $A$, $D$ into $C$, $B$ into $C$, $C$ into $A$ (note $C$ contains $2$), $A$ into $D$, and $D$ into $B$ and done.

The strategy in the first example was a sort of guess and check.  In the second example, I focused on building appropriately-sized "holes" in the larger containers, which made it very easy.